# Rails: How to add a variable length array to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to Rails. I'm trying to design a model with the following structure:

```
Parent

 - Name
 - Date
 - Children
   - Child 1
   - ...
   - Child N
```

Where N is variable and Child has multiple attributes of its own.

Each Child will only be created and edited in the context of its parent, meaning I need a single form to Create/Edit both the Parent and all of its children.

My questions are:

1. Should I implement Child as a separate model with the Parent having many Children, or is it possible to do this as a single flat Parent Model?
2. How would I implement this all as a single form, i.e. all Children are created/modified with the Parent? I would need to create a variable number of Children on the client side and then submit them along with the Parent data, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: The answer to this question depends entirely on the domain. You need to read up on self-referential associations, single table inheritance and the other potential solutions and decide what is right for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

In the order asked:

1. I would add children as a separate model if parents and children have innately unique characteristics.  If not I'd do it as separate objects in the same model (person has many people).  Depends on your needs.
2. You should check out the [cacoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for this, which allows you to dynamically generate fields for child models.  The Github page for the gem has several examples and there are some good youtube videos out there on it.